# google map not displaying on my website since yesterday

Tags: html

The following code is not showing a map on my 'Our location" page the same code was showing when I pasted a week back but today its shows error

> Google Maps Platform rejected your request. Invalid request. Invalid 'pb' parameter

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3773.2559564924227!2d72.80479351419427!3d18.96430018715204!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3be7ce75265bf0e9%3A0xfda2c2b818e14ab9!2sDr.%20Gadkari's%20Dental%20Clinic!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1622984958450!5m2!1sen!2sin" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you please share some code or errors? Otherwise, we cant help much

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code its hard to tell what the problem is.

But if i had to warrant a guess id say there needs to be a `PB` parameter inside your `URL`.

EG `"https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=***Rest of the url****`

SOLUTION - Removing the apostrophe in `Gadkari's` in the URL was causing the issue

Comment: <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3773.2559564924227!2d72.80479351419427!3d18.96430018715204!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3be7ce75265bf0e9%3A0xfda2c2b818e14ab9!2sDr.%20Gadkari's%20Dental%20Clinic!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1622984958450!5m2!1sen!2sin" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>

Comment: The above code is added in custom HTML on-page. check www.gadkarisclinic.com/our-locations/. The other 2 locations are showing map

Comment: It could be the apostrophe in `Gadkari's` that is causing the issue

Comment: Thanks, spacemonki after removing the apostrophe the map is visible now.